# retrieving data from another list

Tags: list

i have two lists (one is customer profile & the other is Bank Tracker) both have common column (Basic customer Number.) ...how can I retrieve all the data /customer info from the customer profile to Bank Tracker by entering the Customer Basic number only

Comment: Which development model are you using CSOM? JSOM? REST API? SSOM?

Answer (score 1):

you need to query in both the list passing the common column i.e "Basic customer Number". Once you query this you will get results from both the list. Now it depends up to you if you want to merge both the tables and then display the record or else you want to bind the values in controls and then display the values in a form.

Comment: hi dear can you provide the steps..  Note that I am using SharePoint 2010

Comment: Use 
Spquery query = new spquery;
query.Query = "Write query here ";
Splistitem item = list.getitem(query)